# VB.NET - Problems with SHQueryRecycleBin

Tags: vb.net, winapi, uint32

I'm currently working on an application for my personal use. The idea is that you can open it up and reach all kind of stats of your computer (Recycle bin, Drives, Network and much more). Now I was working with the `SHQueryRecycleBin` from Win API.

Though I have some problems. And I've tried to look over outdated solutions for VB6 or VB.NET solutions that simply didn't work. I used the code reference from [this source](http://convert.codes-sources.com/file2vb.aspx?ID=35852&f=RecycleBin%5CRecycleBinWin32.cs) and to retrieve the size and count of files I used [this source](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_move_file_to_wastebasket.html).

I put it in an timer, and after those 100 ticks (as I set it) were ran, I got this error:

```
File I/O of a structure with field 'cbSize' of type 'UInt32' is not valid.
```

The type of `cbSize` is `UInteger` which (apparently) automatic changes to an `UInt32` - I think it's based on the system.

You should note that I'm on an Windows 7 x86 (64-bit). If have an solution for this or another piece of code that is easier than use Win API, let me know.

I have looked at the `System.Management` but wanted an bullet proof code that could interact with most systems.

Comment: How are declaring the API function and LPSHQUERYRBINFO struct?  Please provide the code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have vb.net handy to test, but the following code works perfectly well in vb6:

In a module:

```
Public Type SHRECYCLEBININFO
  cbSize As Long
  i64Size As Currency
  i64NumItems As Currency
End Type
Public Declare Function SHQueryRecycleBin Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "SHQueryRecycleBinA" (ByVal pszRootPath As String, pSHQueryRBInfo As SHRECYCLEBININFO) As Long
```

And in a form:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim info As SHRECYCLEBININFO
    Dim res As Long

    info.cbSize = Len(info)
    res = SHQueryRecycleBin("C:\", info)
    MsgBox "size: " & (info.i64Size * 10000) & " bytes" & vbCrLf & "items: " & (info.i64NumItems * 10000)
End Sub
```

Note the use of type "currency" - this is because vb6 doesn't have a normal data type for 64-bit integers.  Type `Currency` is using 8 bytes, but keeps 4 decimal places, hence the multiplication by 10000 to get the results.

Comment: I got it to work. I used the whole library from the project I looked on, and finally got the size and count of files.